# Why does aspect ratio mess up row height?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a simple layout comprised of a `Row` with:

1. Red box on the left that should fill the height and have the same width (square)
2. Column with a couple of texts on the right

```
Row(
    Modifier
        .background(Color.Green)
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
    )
    Column(
        Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .padding(12.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello")
        Text("Welcome")
        Text("Bye")
        Text("Foo")
        Text("Bar")
    }
}
```

The problem is that the last text (`Bar`) is sometimes cut off:
[image]

---

If I add another text (`Hi` for example), `Bar` will become visible but this time `Hi` will get cut off. The issue seems to be the `aspectRatio(1f)` because when I use simple `width(100.dp)`, everything works fine.

Using compose `1.0.5`. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: This is working without issue for me. What version of compose are you using? I tried on 1.1.0-beta03.

Comment: @Francesc I am using `1.0.5`. Tried the version you mentioned in a clean project and when I added one more text, the same issue happened. I guess you need add sufficient amount of texts to reproduce it (in my other project the fonts were larger)

Comment: You are right, after adding a couple more rows I see the issue. This might be a bug in Compose, I would suggest to create a minimal sample project and report it on the issue tracker.